# How to group and return Column1 with total number of "true" in boolean Column2 Linq query and display in View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

**Input**

```
Event  | Attended | Date

Event1 | true     | 10/12/2017 

Event2 | true     | 10/15/2017

Event1 | false    | 10/20/2017

Event2 | true     | 10/30/2017

Event1 | true     | 11/05/2017

Event1 | true     | 11/20/2017

Event1 | true     | 12/01/2017
```

**Output needs to be**

```
Event Name |  Count

Event 1    | 4

Event 2    | 2
```

How do I create a linq query to group the Event column and the "true" count for each event and return it to the view in MVC .NET core EF Core? Do I need to use a ViewModel to display the Event and Count? I have seen several example of `Sum([integer value])`, non like `Sum(a => a.Attended == true ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample for your scenario.

**CLASSES**

```
public class Event
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public bool Attended { get; set; }
}

public class EventResult
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

events.Add(new Event() { EventName = "Event1", Attended = true });
events.Add(new Event() { EventName = "Event2", Attended = true });
events.Add(new Event() { EventName = "Event1", Attended = true });
events.Add(new Event() { EventName = "Event2", Attended = false });

var result = events.GroupBy(e => e.EventName)
            .Select(ev => new EventResult { EventName = ev.First().EventName, Count = ev.Where(et => et.Attended).Count() }).ToList();
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
 var OwnerId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
 var groupedEvents = _context.Events.Where(o => o.OwnerID == OwnerId).GroupBy(e => e.EventName)
                    .Select(ev => new EventResults 
                 { 
                  EventName = ev.First().EventName, 
                  Count = ev.Where(et => et.IsDone).Count() 
                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();

return View(groupedEvents);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcDWOL.Models.EventResult>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                  EventName
                </th>
                <th>
                  Count
               </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName)
            </td>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
            </td>

        </tr>
}  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Return this result from you Controller / ViewModel  to View OR you should have a binding for this one.

Comment: Put Code in one of the Controller /ViewModel of that View.